# How to fix ‘HTTP ERROR 500' after deployment Laravel project?

Tags: laravel, web-deployment, http-error

I deployed the contents of the "public" folder in my Laravel into the "public_html" folder in my host also deployed the rest of the folders into the "core" folder that I created next to the "public_html" folder.
I changed the index.php file information in the "public_html"  folder to this form:

```
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
```

to:

```
require __DIR__.'/../core/vendor/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../core/bootstrap/app.php';
```

And I also set up the database information in the env file.
I checked my PHP version. I use Laravel 5.7 and my PHP version is 7.3.3

Comment: Check your laravel and apache/nginx `log` files. Add the actual stack trace (error) here.

Comment: Can you post the output of ls -h so we can see the owner and the permissions of the core folder?

Comment: check if you could ssh your server and excecute 'composer update' there

Answer (score 0):

I think that the solution after we relocated the public folder is to  change the index file as you have changed:

```
# These two lines should be changed...
require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/start.php';

# ... into these two lines.
require __DIR__.'/../laravel/bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../laravel/bootstrap/start.php';
```

then we should configure .htaccess inside your www folder this is the tree of www folder

```
config/
logs/
www/
    app/
    bootstrap/
    public/
        packages/
        .htaccess
        index.php
        ...
    vendor/
    ...
```

then inside  .htaccess place the following .htaccess file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Your Laravel application should now work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the "Internal Server Error 500" issue also, but I was reading direct from the  public folder (I normally assign root folder as mylaravelfolder/public to a domain). I changed that and added a .htaccess file  on the root folder to read from public. It worked fine

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```